# dovecot WILDCARD SSL (certicate.crt, private.key, intermediate.crt) not working

Tags: ubuntu, smtp, postfix, dovecot

I have installed dovecot and postfix and got it working, but when I change the ssl_cert_file, ssl_key_file and ssl_ca_file dovecot configuration to my wildcard SSL certificate (working on Apache) it simply does not work. It is not a file permission problem, I'm pretty sure.

The output of the command

`openssl s_client -connect localhost:993` is:

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
write:errno=104

no peer certificate available

No client certificate CA names sent

SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 263 bytes

New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
```

When I use the self-signed SSL, I got the correct output and the thing works. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you checked Dovecot's log file?

Comment: Try adding `-servername <your server name>` to the openssl command? Make sure the server name you pass is covered by the wildcard cert. Does it make a difference?

Comment: Doh, 2014! Oops..